# Order of derivation if calculus of variation

Tags: calculus-of-variations, classical-mechanics

In reading the derivation of the relativistic free particle (covariant) equation of motion by extremising the relativistic action $-mc\int_A^B \, ds$, I stumbled upon a passage where the author inverts the order of the $d$ (derivation) and $\delta$ (variation) symbols: $d(\delta x^{\mu})= \delta (dx^{\mu})$, how is that possible? Given that the symbol $\delta x^{\mu}$ should represent an infinitesimal function (a variation) so it shouldn't even make sense to separate the two symbols.

Comment: The notation on such matters is very confused. My preference is not to think of $\delta x^\mu$ as an infinitesimal function, but rather a vector field which says in which direction (at each point) you are varying the trajectory. Then $d\delta = \delta d$ is just the statement that Lie derivatives commute with exterior derivatives.